# How to hide dates not in current month in CalendarPickerView Android Library

Tags: android

I am using https://github.com/savvisingh/DateRangePicker with current 1.3.0 version.

My current implementation is showing dates from months before and after the current selected month (circled in red)
[image]

I want to be able to hide these like the example in the github link above, shown in the picture below
[image]

From my understanding the solution is most likely done in the colors.xml file, but I cannot find  the specific attribute to add/set to #00000000 in order to hide.

For reference,
`<color name="dateTimeRangePickerStateDefault">@color/white</color>`
will change the current months dates color but not change the dates from the previous and next month.

Answer (score 0):

Found adding this to colors.xml allows changing color of days outside of current month. #00000000 sets to transparent in order to hide.

```
<color name="dateTimeRangePickerStateNonSelectable">#00000000</color>
```